# WSO2 Governance Registry upgrade - DB Scripts Issue

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

We are doing a DB Upgradation for WSo2 Governance Registry upgradation from 4.5.3 to 4.6.0. The sql scripts available in the documentation for creating some db schema in staging database is having discrepancy like scripts for creating few tables are missing. Can anyone provide valid scripts for staging database as we are trying out with mySql/Oracle database?

The reference link I am following is shown as below:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

Comment: Have you identified any missing tables? Are you trying to migrate from MySQL to Oracle? If so it is not possible according to the documentation.

Comment: Yes, we have identified the missing tables from 4.5.3 sql migration script.We are not migrating from MySQL to Oracle. We are migrating in our local environment from MySQL to MySQL for PoC purpose. We are planning to do the same in higher environment using Oracle to Oracle. We know that from one db to another db the migration script will not work. Please guide us.

Comment: Can you specify what are the missing tables you have identified?

Comment: the tables which got created are:
um_domain, um_module, um_module_actions, um_system_role, um_system_user, um_system_user_role
And Missing tables are UM_TENANT, UM_ROLE, UM_USER, UM_PERMISSION, UM_ROLE_PERMISSION, UM_USER_PERMISSION, UM_CLAIM, UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE

Comment: We found there is a discrepancy in 4.5.3 sql migration script for MySQL. For instance, there is foreign key which has not been specified for 4.5.3 for MySQL migration script. Please check that and guide us how to proceed further.